# MongoDB query returns empty array for one thing but not another

Tags: mongodb

I'm working on a basic app that returns a list of books based on the genre and subgenre. However, when I test the backend on postman, it returns an empty array and I'm unsure if this has to do with my routes or the actual code that generates this list.

This is what my route looks like.

```
  // get books based on the genre
  router.get('/books/:genre', bookBuilder.get_some_books)

  // get books based on multiple queries
  router.get('/books/:genre&subgenre', bookBuilder.get_these_books)
```

This is the code that queries my MongoDB database

```
// getting book by genre & subgenre
exports.get_these_books = async function (req, res) {
  let { genre, subgenre } = req.params;
  try {
    let books = await Book.find({"genre": genre, "subgenre": {$all: [subgenre]}});
    if (books) {
      res.json(books)
    } else {
      res.status(404).send({error: 'Not Found'});
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({error: err.message});
  }
}
```

Getting a list of books by genre works just fine. But getting by genre AND subgenre is proving to be difficult.

EDIT:

The example document is

```
title:"Ghost Squad"
author: Array
genre:"MG"
subgenre: Array
    0:"Ghost Story"
    1:"Fantasy Fiction"
description:"Shortly before Halloween, Lucely and her best friend, Syd, cast a spel..."
```

As you can see, the subgenre is an array.

Comment: 1) post your example document, 2) what is the type of `subgenre` field in your schema 3)  show `console.log(subgenre)` output.

Comment: @turivishal i've added the edit. but the console.log(subgenre) isn't showing anything somehow

Comment: @Rhys I'm not sure if you can pass 2 parameters to Express route like this: `/books/:genre&subgenre`. You put console.log(subgenre) after the line `let { genre, subgenre } = req.params;` and receive nothing ?

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh you were right, I needed to change the express route. i changed it to /books/:genre/:subgenre and it works better like this